# Calculate log base 2

Tags: fortran

I am using Fortran 95 using Silverfrost Plato where I need to calculate log to the base 2. How do we do it since the in built has only natural log and base10?

Answer (score 6):

The [formula for changing the base of a logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) is

```
log_b(x) = log_k(x) / log_k(b)
```

Applied to your case this becomes the following in Fortran:

```
real function log2(x)
  implicit none
  real, intent(in) :: x

  log2 = log(x) / log(2.)
end function
```